# Word Interop Creating Blank Labels Document

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

If Anyone happens to know, how would I create a word document that is a blank page of labels? There are a million and one guides to performing a mail merge, but I am not looking to do that. I simply want a blank word document that I will throw sequential numbers in.

I have created the document as such...

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document

    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
```

This creates and opens a simple word document. How would I insert into the document a label page? The type of label is irrelevant, I am hoping to be able to tell from its creation how to interact with it as needed.

Any  and all help help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is listed below.

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
    oDoc = oWord.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument(Name:="L7163", Address:="This is some text", AutoText:="MyLabelLayout", LaserTray:=Nothing)
```

This creates a single page of mailing labels with "This is some text" displayed on each. The version of the mailing labels is Avery L7163. The only problem is that it creates the initial active document and a second label page. This is resolved as such..

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
    Dim ActiveDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument
    ActiveDoc = oWord.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument(Name:="L7163", Address:="sdvsdv", AutoText:="MyLabelLayout", LaserTray:=Nothing)
    oDoc.Close(False, , )
```

This does the same thing except it sets the labels as the active document and then closes the blank document.